# Oracle Contains Function Returning False BLOB Positives

Tags: oracle, pdf, blob, contains

I'm using the Contains function to search for strings in BLOB fields containing PDFs or Word documents. Recently I did the following search:

```
SELECT doc_id 
FROM   table_of_documents
WHERE  CONTAINS (BLOB_FIELD, 'SDS.IF.00005') > 0
```

Most of the records returned were correct, but a few had PDFs in them that did not have "`SDS.IF.00005`" in them but did have "`SDS.EL.00005`" in them.

When I say the PDFs did not have the search term, I mean I opened them in Adobe reader and searched them using the search function and my own eyeballs, and also people extremely familiar with the documents insist that the term is not there and should not be there.

I tried treating the dots as escape characters: `SDS\\.IF\\.00005` and `{SDS.IF.00005}`. However, I am still getting the same results.

I also tried setting `CONTAINS (BLOB_FIELD, 'SDS.IF.00005') = 100`, but I'm still getting documents with `SDS.EL.00005` in them and not `SDS.IF.00005`.

Do the dots in the search term mean something like `SDS.%.00005` to Oracle? Or should I be researching how to find deep hidden text in Adobe documents that's not visible to the naked eye or to the Adobe text search function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, [`CONTAINS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#BABGAIHJ) is a Oracle Text function that performs [*full text search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search), so Oracle is tokenizing your string, probably according to its [BASIC_LEXER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cdatadic.htm#i1007615). This lexer uses `.` as a word separator. So Oracle understands your query as "return anything that matches at least one of the words 'SDS', 'IF' or '00005'". As your PDF will probably have been indexed using that same lexer, from Oracle Text point of view your PDF contains the words 'SDS', 'EL' and '00005', so it matches 2 of 3 words and so Oracle returns that row.

Actually, 'IF' is included in [Oracle Text default](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/astopsup.htm#i634475) [stopword list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) (words that are ignored because they are so common that they mostly introduce "noise"); so your query actually is "return anything that matches at least one of 'SDS' or '00005'". Therefore I am not surprised that a PDF that contains the literal text "SDS.EL.00005" will give you `CONTAINS(BLOB_FIELD, 'SDS.IF.00005') = 100` (a "perfect" match) as you wrote.

If you want to search for a verbatim string, I think you should rather not use Oracle Text and just implement a solution using plain old [`DBMS_LOB.INSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i998546). If that is not viable, then you will have to find a way to make Oracle Text index those strings without tokenizing them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look in the BASIC_LEXER link and also DBMS_LOB.INSTR.